# Alert message on Page_Init

Tags: c#, javascript, alert, code-behind, page-init

I have a security class that is called by a PageBase class (that all pages will inherit from) that will redirect the user to either the home page or the login page (depending on if they're logged in or not), if they try and access a page they aren't authorized to see. I want to alert the user of this by saying something like,

`"You are not authorized to view this page, redirecting you"`

Or something like that. I know you can call javascript from your codebehind to show an alert to the user.

In my PageBase class, (again, that all pages will inherit from), there is a common Page_Init(..) method, and when I try and call my js alert from there, nothing happens. I've put breakpoints in my code, and the code is being hit, but the user isn't getting the alert. I assume this is because Page_Init is too early in the page's lifecycle to execute js, and that that is what is causing this issue.

Is there a way around this without having to add a function to each individual page? Also, here are the two ways I have tried:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as System.Web.UI.Page;
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You do not have access to this page. You are being redirected')", true);
```

and

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You do not have access to this page. You are being redirected');</script>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is NOT that there isn't any page on the Page_Init.  The problem is that the server is not sending out anything to the browser because it's too early in the [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  (more coming)

Under normal circumstances, response data is not sent to the browser until the Rendering event, even if you call Response.Write.  This can often be forced by calling [Response.Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx) immediately after Response.Write BUT that often has unintended consequences.  In the Page_Init cycle, I think that calling Response.Flush() would probably cause you plenty of problems.

You might be better served simply creating a static html page with the "we're redirecting" message, and using a javascrip.SetTimeout method to count down and use javascript to redirect after a few seconds.  That's how it's been done on the web for years.  Your base class can simply redirect to this page when the user is not authorized.

Code for the "redirect" page.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function delayedRedirect(){
     window.location = "/default.aspx"
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)">
 <h2>You are not authorized to view this page, redirecting you</h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: yeah...wasn't exactly sure how to word it...but I figured that was the issue. Is there a way around this, since all of the work done by the security class is done during `Page_Init`? I'm not opposed to doing some C# coding to make a custom alert, I just need to alert the user somehow

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but it works :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do implement the logic on Page_Load event on the base page as so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "keykey", "alert('You do not have access to this page. You are being redirected'); window.location='http://caracol.com.co';", true);
```

Comment: this is what I was trying to avoid since each page has it's own `Page_Load` event, but the security logic I am trying to implement is controlled in a parent `PageBase` class during the `Page_Init` event

Comment: I don't know if I am not understanding but... can't you just move the security logic to OnLoad on PageBase and solve it that way?